# Function is never used for methods annotated with OnLifecycleEvent in LifecycleObserver

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components

There is custom CustomLifecycleObserver:

```
class CustomLifecycleObserver : LifecycleObserver {

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
    fun onCreate() {
        Logger.tag("SOME-TAG").d("ON_CREATE")
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun onStart() {
        Logger.tag("SOME-TAG").d("ON_START")
    }
}

somewhere.lifecycle.addObserver(CustomLifecycleObserver())
```

Both methods **onCreate** and **onStart** is marked as unused in latest Android Studio 3.6.3. Is there some proper way to make it "used" without SuppressWarnings?

Comment: Try using `DefaultLifecycleObserver` instead.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce What do you mean by DefaultLifecycleObserver? Can you give an example?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/DefaultLifecycleObserver

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, Thank you! I missed it.